# Which command is used to shows the list of stored procedures in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Which command is used to shows  the list of  stored procedures in database

how to show the  list of procedures  in database either in command or work bench please show anyone

Answer (score 0):

Using Command Line Or In MYSQL Workbench;

You can [execute following command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-status.html) :

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

It shall show you a table with information about all stored procedures in the current database.

If you have multiple databases and you want to select a particular database;
You can use the following command :

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = 'your_db_name';
```

The information table will have columns for `Db`, `Name`, `Type`, `Definer`, `Modified`, `Created`, `Security_type`, `Comment`, `character_set_client`, `collation_connection`, `Database Collation`.